# how to style block of text so that rtl text to be aligned in right and ltr text aligned left?

Tags: html, css

I have a block of content contains **both** left-to-right and right-to-left text
and I want to display both correctly.

1. if the user started with **ltr** text , the direction to be **ltr** and text-align **left**
2. and if the user  started with **rtl** text , the direction to be **rtl** and text-align to be **right**

I wanna do that with only CSS .

I think we should have something like this , But `direction Auto` is not exist

```
.content {
direction : auto // rtl for rtl text and vice versa
text-align : auto 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir="auto"` in HTML, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) :

```html
<p dir="rtl">This paragraph is in English but incorrectly goes right to left.</p>
<p dir="ltr">This paragraph is in English and correctly goes left to right.</p>
<p dir="auto">This paragraph is in English and correctly goes left to right.</p>

<hr>

<p>هذه الفقرة باللغة العربية ولكن بشكل خاطئ من اليسار إلى اليمين.</p>
<p dir="auto">هذه الفقرة باللغة العربية ، لذا يجب الانتقال من اليمين إلى اليسار.</p>
```